# Program only throws exception when variable is defined in "try"

Tags: html, url, try-catch, processing

I am trying to write a program that will read a webpage.  The following code is not valid:

```
String[] lines;
try {
  lines = loadStrings(url);
}
catch(IOException e) {
  return;
}
```

But this code is:

```
try {
  String[] lines = loadStrings(url);
}
catch(IOException e) {
  return;
}
```

I cannot use the code in the second example because I need to use the variable "lines" later in the program.  Is there some other way to catch this exception (504 error)?

Example:

```
PFont f;
String webpage;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);  
  f = createFont("Arial", 16);
}


void draw() {  
  background(255); 
  textFont(f);
  fill(0);    
  text("Press Return to Start", 25, 90);
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (key == '\n') {
    webpage = "processing.org";
    loadData(webpage);
  }
}


void loadData(String webpage) {

  String url = "www.processing.org";
  try {
    String[] lines = loadStrings(url);
  }
  catch(IOException e) {
    return;
  }
  saveStrings("Stuff on Webpage.txt", lines);
}
```

This is where the program crashes:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://www.processing.org/
```

In the event of this exception, I would like the program to exit out of the loadData function and continue with keyPressed.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: I have updated it with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
String message;

if(random(1) < .5) {
  message = "hello";
}

println(message);
```

This code will generate an error that says `message cannot be resolved to a variable`. This is because the compiler is smart enough to know that depending on what the `if` statement does, `message` might not contain a value. **Processing / Java does not assign a default value to local variables.**

We could fix this compiler error by assigning a default value ourselves:

```
String message = null;

if(random(1) < .5) {
  message = "hello";
}

println(message);
```

Now `message` has a default value of `null`, which matches what happens with sketch / class variables by default.

Another way we could fix this is by putting the `println()` call inside the `if` statement:

```
String message;

if(random(1) < .5) {
  message = "hello";
  println(message);
}
```

We could simplify this a bit:

```
if(random(1) < .5) {
  String message = "hello";
  println(message);
}
```

Now, back to your code:

```
try {
  String[] lines = loadStrings(url);
}
catch(IOException e) {
  return;
}
saveStrings("Stuff on Webpage.txt", lines);
```

This doesn't work because `lines` is declared inside the `try` block, so it goes **out of scope** outside of that block, and you can't use it afterwards.

```
String[] lines;
try {
  lines = loadStrings(url);
}
catch(IOException e) {
  return;
}
saveStrings("Stuff on Webpage.txt", lines);
```

This doesn't work, because the compiler is not smart enough to see that `return` statement. It just knows that one branch of the code skips over the `lines = loadStrings(url);` line, so it knows that `lines` might be unassigned when you try to use it.

You can fix this by either assigning a default value yourself, or moving everything to be inside the same block, just like we did with our simplified example above.